# Drawing a track on top of a map picture with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a collection of [x,y] pairs of points that represent some coordinates, and a picture representing a map. I would like to draw on top of the picture the track made by the coordinate pairs. I tried using `imshow`, `figimage`, new axes `offsetImage`, `annotationBBox` etc. but nothing really works well. For example the `annotationBBox` seemed like the best choice, but for some reason it always draws on top of the plot, and if I set the offset too high it disappears altogether from the final plot. I couldn't get `imshow` to crop the image without doing it manually, which is a pain, and `figimage` also doesn't support any sort of zooming functionality.

I am fine with manually tweaking the coordinates/rotation of the map until everything fits properly.

What I would not want is some GIS solution - the map and coordinates are custom and have no connection to the real world/GPS coordinates.

An example piece of code that plots the coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
waypoints = [[0, -1, -4, -6, -6], [0, 0, 4, 4, 3]]
plt.plot(waypoints[0], waypoints[1], 'o-')
plt.grid(False)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', left=False, right=False, labelleft=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: Original plot]

An example map:

[image: Map]

And the final result combination should look like this:

[image: Map+plot]

Comment: You need to have some relation that maps the image extents to data coordiantes, or the data to image coordinates.

Comment: As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said you need coordinates. If you have these i would suggest using pygmaps to plot on a map. you can define paths consisting of points with (lat, lon) coordinates.

Comment: You may use `plotly` - https://plot.ly/python/lines-on-maps/ - or another similar library.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear here. You only need two coordinate pairs to unambiguously determine the coordinate transform between line data and image data. There is no need for any special library or other external source. But without the coordinate pair there is no way of correctly positionning the line wrt. the image or vice versa.

Comment: Well, I already have that, for example [0,0] would be [475,187] on the picture, [-1, 0] is [437,194] etc. What I don't know is how to actually plot this - what functionality from matplotlib to use in order to draw a part of a picture, then plot something on top of it. The plotly library uses GIS/latlong coordinates, so I'm not sure it's useful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two pairs of points which correspond to each other in the different coordinate systems allows to define a transform between the systems. You may add this transform to the data transform of the line to get the lines in the coordinates of the image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

def get_transform_2pts(q1, q2, p1, p2):
    """ create transform to transform from q to p, 
        such that q1 will point to p1, and q2 to p2 """
    ang = np.arctan((p2-p1)[1] /(p2-p1)[0])-np.arctan((q2-q1)[1] /(q2-q1)[0])
    s = np.abs(np.sqrt(np.sum((p2-p1)**2))/np.sqrt(np.sum((q2-q1)**2)))
    trans = Affine2D().translate(*-q1).rotate(ang).scale(s).translate(*p1)
    return trans


image = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue5oH.png")
y0 = image.shape[0]
waypoints = [[0, -1, -4, -6, -6], [0, 0, 4, 4, 3]]

# Coordinates for transformation.
lc1 = np.array([0,0])
ic1 = np.array([475, y0-187])

lc2 = np.array([-1, 0])
ic2 = np.array([437, y0-194])

trans = get_transform_2pts(lc1, lc2, ic1, ic2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(np.flipud(image), origin="lower")

plt.plot(waypoints[0], waypoints[1], 'o-', transform=trans+ax.transData)

ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if you want to autoscale only on the line,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")

plt.plot(waypoints[0], waypoints[1], 'o-', transform=trans+ax.transData)

ax.autoscale(False)
ax.imshow(np.flipud(image), origin="lower")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you! Is there any way to zoom in on the image portion that has the data, to make it look like the picture in my question?